# Deploy only files necessary to run a WPF application?

Tags: wpf

I created a WPF app and when I give it to an end-use, I only want to give them what is necessary to run the app, in other words, none of the stuff that is used for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

When you build a release application, this is what is generated (by default).  The debugging information (such as the .pdb files) are not generated in a release build.

Comment: I did this, but I still see .pdb files? Would I just have to copy the release directory and give it to someone.  What about third party libraries not found in the release directory.

Comment: @Xaisoft You will need to include everything they require.  I would recommend making a setup project or use an installer, though - as it will also let you correctly deploy the .NET framework, etc.  (The .pdb files aren't built in release by default - but that's a project option)